# Why are my drop down menus unclickable and my pages tabs are not consistently functioning?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, tabs, blogger

So I see some variations of my question we asked, but none of the solutions worked for my blog. http://icantaffordmylifestyle.blogspot.com/

So I've been messing around with perfecting this code for days now and it's driving me nuts that I can't figure it out.  The About, Contact, lifestyle, and Om-Nomnom page are all not opening up if I have clicked one of the other tabs first. I have to click the home link first to refresh.  So It only works if it is the first one to be clicked on or I go home before clicking a new link.  Then the drop down boxes won't work either!  They worked fine when I was still trying to get the links to work at all and had it at the bottom of my page, but now that I have moved it to the top of my page where it belongs it stopped working.  The drop box disappears too quickly to click on anything unless I move it fast enough and in just the right spot. How do I get my links to work more consistently and get the drop downs to work better?

Here is the html:

```
<div id='mbtnavbar'> 
<ul id='mbtnav'> 
  <li>   <a href=/ >| HOME/</a> 
  </li> 
  <li>
  <a href="p/about_12.html"> | ABOUT </a> 
         </li> 
 <li>
  <a href="p/pradvertising.html"> |  CONTACT/ SERVICES</a> 
         </li> 
<li> 
  <a href= "search/label/Lifestyle">| LIFESTYE LOOKS</a> 
</li> 
<li> 
  <a href="search/label/Daily%20Look%20Book">| OOTD FASHIONS</a> 
</li>
    <li><a href="p/Lifestyle_9.htm">| LIFESTYLE</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="search/label/Music">| MUSIC</a></li>
            <li><a href="search/label/DIY">| DIY</a></li>
            <li><a href="search/label/My%20Art">| MY ART</a></li>
            <li><a href="search/label/Nail%20Art">| NAIL ART</a></li>
            <li><a href="search/label/Life">| LIFE</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="p/nom.html">| OM-NOMNOM </a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="search/label/Nom%20Diaries">| NOM DIARIES</a></li>
            <li><a href="search/label/Nomventure">| NOM-ventures</a></li>
            <li><a href="search/label/Beverage%20Adventures">| LINKS TO MY DRINKS</a></li>
            <li><a href="search/label/Healthy%20Nom">| HEALTHY NOMS</a></li>

        </ul>
    </li>

    <!-- etc. -->

</ul></div>
```

& the CSS is here:

```
/*----- MBT Drop Down Menu ----*/ 
<center>
#mbtnavbar { 
/* background: #ffffff; */ 
width: 100%; 
color: #3cd0b6; 
margin: 0px; 
padding: 0; 
position: relative; 
border-top:0px solid #ffffff; 
height: 41px; 
vertical-align: text-middle;
} 

#mbtnav { 
background: #ffffff; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
} 

#mbtnav ul { 
float: center; 
list-style: none; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
} 

#mbtnav li { 
list-style: none; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
/* border-left:1px solid#ffffff; 
border-right:1px solid #ffffff; */ 
height:41px;
vertical-align: text-middle;
}  

#mbtnav li a, #mbtnav li a:link, #mbtnav li a:visited { 
color: #3cd0b6; 
display: block; 
font:bold 24px sue ellen francisco; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 9px 12px 10px 12px; 
text-decoration: none; 
} 

#mbtnav li a:hover, #mbtnav li a:active { 
background: #ffffff; 
color: #3cd0b6; 
display: block; 
text-decoration: none; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 9px 12px 10px 12px; 
} 

#mbtnav li { 
float: left; 
padding: 0; 
} 

#mbtnav li ul { 
z-index: 9999; 
position: absolute; 
left: -999em; 
height: auto; 
width: 200px; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
} 

#mbtnav li ul a { 
width: 180px; 
} 

#mbtnav li ul ul { 
margin: -35px 0 0 161px; 
} 

#mbtnav li:hover ul ul, #mbtnav li:hover ul ul ul, #mbtnav li.sfhover ul ul, #mbtnav li.sfhover ul ul ul { 
left: -999em; 
} 

#mbtnav li:hover ul, #mbtnav li li:hover ul, #mbtnav li li li:hover ul, #mbtnav li.sfhover ul, #mbtnav li li.sfhover ul, #mbtnav li li li.sfhover ul { 
left: auto; 
} 

#mbtnav li:hover, #mbtnav li.sfhover { 
position: static; 
} 

#mbtnav li li a, #mbtnav li li a:link, #mbtnav li li a:visited { 
background: #ffffff; 
/* width: 140px; */ 
color: #3cd0b6; 
display: block; 
font:bold 16px sue ellen francisco; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 9px 12px 10px 12px; 
text-decoration: none; 
z-index:9999; 
border-bottom:1px dotted #333; 
} 

#mbtnav li li a:hover, #mbtnavli li a:active { 
background: #ffffff; 
color: #FC9F35; 
display: block; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 9px 12px 10px 12px; 
text-decoration: none; 
} 

.tabs-inner .widget #mbtnavbar li a { 
border-left:none; 
} 

.tabs-outer .widget, .section { 
margin:0; 
} 

.tabs-inner { 
padding: 0px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your `li` height:

```
#mbtnav li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 41px; <-this one
    vertical-align: text-middle;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but that seems to only cut off the bottom of my links without making the space smaller.  I'm assuming thats why it is so difficult to click the links.  Also have any ideas why my links wont work if I try to go from page to page?

Comment: Actually I got it to work now! OMG, Thanks so much.  Do you have any idea why the pages won't open properly if I try to click them one after another?

Comment: @user3184598 I don't know what you mean here, I'm opening them without no problem, sure there is a little too much delay before it loads, but it loads in the end.

Comment: Okay, click the about tab, then click the contact tab. It does not work.  But if you click the about tab and then the home button and the contact tab it will.  I can't go from page to page.

Comment: Because you have `p/` before each link, and it points to that direction, it seems your hompage is outside that `p` directory and once you enter in that `p` directory and try to click the about page, since it's pointing again to a `p` directory it won't open... Did I manage to confuse you ? xd

Comment: What can I do to fix it.  because that is the link to get to pages. will it open if I remove the p?

Comment: Move your files as the same folder as your homepage and change the links, or have only the homepage links points to that directory and remove `p/` from the subpages links.

Comment: I'm not sure I can do that.  Or how to.  I use blogger and its either posts or pages.  Do you know how I could do this right?

Comment: Sry but can't help you there, don't have exp with blogger.